# Issues with receiving push notifications -

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem where I don't receive notifications every time I push them to the device. I do receive them occasionally or after a big delay. I'm using the development certificate for APNS and Ruby on Rails on the server side. The server does send notifications to the Apple server its only when I'm receiving them I have a problem.

I initially thought it was a problem with global notifications (tunnel being closed) and to test it I sent my device a notification to Skype which was received almost instantaneously. So, I really dont understand whats the problem here. Is there anything I'm missing or how do I trouble shoot it in depth.

Are push notifications reliable and whats the latency involved? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hey Malinois, sorry about the late reply. I'm still carrying out my testing and eliminating all possible things. Will have to build my app in Adhoc as suggested by you before I get a complete picture of the things.

And yeah, your answer sure helped me go in the right direction, I ll mark it as resolved once I complete my testing.

Thanks again :)) appreciate the prompt response.

Comment: No problem, I'm here to help you. Let me know if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In development, the sending of push notification is not reliable. Some notifications may arrive with some delay. You can try to send notifications in production by building your app in adhoc.
If you haven't the same result with different iphone/ipod, you can try to reset network settings device.

Comment: Hey Malinois,thanks for the prompt reponse, really appreciate it. And yeah, I think the problem is on Apple's side when we are using a development certificate