# APNS - Invalid Registration message

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I created a simple iOS app and enabled push notification.

I am using Windows Azure as my server.

I followed steps to enable push notification (using development certificate) and created device token successfully.

Then I pushed a notification from the server. I got below error message.

```
Push notification sent:  { multicast_id: "some random number",
  success: 0,
  failure: 1,
  canonical_ids: 0,
  results: [ { error: 'InvalidRegistration' } ],
  invalidIds: [ "my device token" ],
  updatedIds: {} }
```

I deleted my app and recreated device token. But, I got the same device token.
I also checked whether i get a response in didReceiveRemoteNotification. I don't.

I tried it all over again, but the same results. Could anyone suggest what the issue could be?

Comment: which tutorial did you follow (if any)? did you see... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719297/not-receiving-push-notification-on-ios-with-azure-notification-hub-didreceivere ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling with it sometime, I finally figured out a way. Thought of sharing the same with everyone.

I made a couple of changes to resolve the issue.

1. The device token returned by Apple will have both brackets and spaces. Azure documentation mentions only to remove brackets before using the token for notification purpose. But, we have to remove both brackets and spaces.
2. We shouldn't keep any inactive device tokens in server. For some reason, when I trigger notifications to both active and inactive device tokens, I don't see any notifications on any of the active devices. When I remove inactive tokens and then trigger notifications, I see notifications on all the active devices.

That said, all is working fine for now!