# Azure Notifications Hub device registrations not working

Tags: ios, swift, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to use Azure Notifications hub in my SwiftUI App. In the debug my app say it is registered for Push notifications but it doesn't show op in Azure. I used this code to setup notifications and used token based authentication in Azure.

I followed this manuals?

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/notification-hubs/ios-sdk-get-started
2. https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-ios

   ```
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AppSettings", ofType: "plist") {
        if let configValues = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
            connectionString = configValues["NotificationsHubConnectionString"] as? String
            hubName = configValues["NotificationsHubName"] as? String

            if (!(connectionString ?? "").isEmpty && !(hubName ?? "").isEmpty)
            {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self;
                MSNotificationHub.setDelegate(self)
                MSNotificationHub.start(connectionString: connectionString!, hubName: hubName!)
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    fatalError("Please setup NotificationsHubConnectionString and NotificationsHubName in AppSettings.plist and restart application")
   ```

   }

How do I get this to work?

Comment: You can refer to [Not receiving push notification on iOS with Azure Notification Hub- didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719297/not-receiving-push-notification-on-ios-with-azure-notification-hub-didreceivere?rq=1) and [Azure Notification Hub - Devices suddenly not receiving notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/340309/azure-notification-hub-devices-suddenly-not-receiv.html)

Comment: I solved one part I used the SwiftUI2 example from azure-notification-hubs. and I can sand push notifications manually with curl on the command line. I followed this guide: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools. I'm still see no registrations in Azure